# Why can't I open a websocket connection to Django Rest API

Tags: django, reactjs, rest, websocket

[image]

I am using react hooks. When I try to establish a websocket connection to my local Django Rest Api, it says

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/api/' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200`

Comment: Does django support websockets out of the box? The error suggests that there is no websocket support at that url.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't support them out of the box...

Comment: So then you have to fix this on the Django side, it's probably not a front-end problem.